# Read through dynamic JSON in php

Tags: php

I'm needing to know how to read through JSON in PHP that I don't know the key's for.  Here is an example of a json that I would need to be going through however none of the key->value pair are always going to be the same.  Some of these key names can be spelled different or have numbers on the end of the names so I need to be able to have them dynamic.

Here is an exact example of the JSON I would be cycling through

```
[  
   {  
      "var5":"item-company-1",
      "asd2":"item-company-1",
      "tie1":"0",
      "cxs1":"481.891px",
      "xcve2":"130.563px"
   },...
```

I understand if I know the exact name of the key I would do something like..

```
 $someObject = json_decode($someJSON);
  print_r($someObject);      // Dump all data of the Object
  echo $someObject[0]->name; // Access Object data
```

However I don't know the keys.  I assume a for next loop would have to be created to cycle through each object, but I have no clue how to do that in PHP.

Comment: do you know if the structure of your json is always the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im assuming your json is always of the below format

```
$json = '[  
   {  
      "var5":"item-company-1",
      "asd2":"item-company-1",
      "tie1":"0",
      "cxs1":"481.891px",
      "xcve2":"130.563px"
   },
   {  
      "var6":"item-company-2",
      "asd7":"item-company-2",
      "tie8":"0",
      "cxs9":"481.891px",
      "xcve10":"130.563px",
      "extra" : "unknown"
   }
]';
```

Then you can convert the whole `JSON` into an array and run a loop

```
$array = json_decode ($json ,true);

foreach ($array as $item) {
    foreach($item as $key => $value) {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I marked the answer because he technically answered my question.

I also found this solution hopefully it might help someone in the future as a great alternative to the above. This will actually go over a multi-level array to get out all the values.

```
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        echo "$key:\n";
    } else {
        echo "$key => $val\n";
    }
}
```